# How to use jsHint to extract code metrics in the CLI report?

Tags: javascript, jshint

I am trying to get code metrics from `jshint` like on [jshint.com](https://jshnit.com):

```
Metrics

There is only one function in this file.

It takes no arguments.

This function contains 2 statements.

Cyclomatic complexity number for this function is 1.
```

The `cli` execution only shows linting outputs, like `missing semicolon` etc., But does not output any of these metrics. However, the above link seems to do that just fine for any pasted code.

How can I get such a code report across *all* JS files/modules? Technically this information should be available but I'm unable to have any output similar to the above via the CLI. Rummaging through the source code it seems entirely possible but I can't figure out if there's an *easier* way than hacking at the source code.

Answer (score 0):

After rummaging through the source code *and* checking out the online docs, it seems you can write your own *reporter* as shown [here](https://jshint.com/docs/reporters/). However, it fails to mention that you can also add additional arguments to get additional information in callback as seen in the code in its [cli.js](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/057b1c6e8e17b8d9e1ddb8254bb44b4bc5ece710/src/cli.js#L682):

Combining the two here's how you can write your custom reporter function that prints the metrics to the console. It's a crude example modified from one in the [repo](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/reporter.js) in case someone stumbles on this:

```
module.exports = {
    reporter: function (res,data,options) {
        //console.dir(data,{depth:5}) //To see entire object
        data.forEach(d => {
            d.functions.forEach(f => {
                console.log(d.file, f.name, f.param, f.metrics);
            });
        });
    }
};
```